# arrow flight sql in dremio odbc/jdbc driver

Tags: node.js, apache-arrow, dremio, apache-arrow-flight

I am implementing Nodejs client to connect to Dremio data source using Dremio odbc driver. Is arrow flight sql connector used in the implementation of ODBC Dremio driver? can someone help me understand

Comment: you could use dremio REST endpoint to connect from your nodes js app

Comment: thank you .. using  node js api , we need to make two calls .. to extract the job id api and later pass to job id to sql api to fetch the result correct ?